# htaccess url rewriting - hide file extensions on URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, friendly-url

## Currently

#### It already works if I add a href like that

`<a href="central-cliente">Click here to go to the client center</a>`

#### But most my links are like this, and it displays clientarea.php in URL - Should overwrite it and be central-cliente, as set in .htaccess

`<a href="clientarea.php">Click here to go to the client center</a>`

### The issue

I want the client to see the friendly url even if he clicks the unfriendly url (.php, .html, etc)

## .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
Options -MultiViews
RewriteBase /painel/

RewriteRule ^central-cliente$ ./clientarea.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^registro$ ./register.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^entrar$ ./clientarea.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^sair$ ./logout.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^whois-dominio$ ./domainchecker.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^pagina-inicial$ ./index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^sua-conta$ ./clientarea.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^base-conhecimento$ ./knowledgebase.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^tickets-suporte$ ./submitticket.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^status-servidor$ ./serverstatus.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^recuperar-senha$ ./pwreset.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^status-servidor$ ./serverstatus.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^tickets-suporte-geral$ ./submitticket.php?step=2&deptid=1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^central-cliente$ ./clientportal.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^meus-dados$ ./clientarea.php?action=details [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^meus-servicos$ ./clientarea.php?action=products [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^meus-dominios$ ./clientarea.php?action=domains [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^meus-orcamentos$ ./clientarea.php?action=quotes [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^minhas-faturas$ ./clientarea.php?action=invoices [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^meus-tickets$ ./supporttickets.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^afiliados$ ./affiliates.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^meus-emails$ ./clientarea.php?action=emails [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^sair$ ./logout.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^enviar-ticket$ ./submitticket.php?step=2&deptid=1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^download$ ./downloads.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^carrinho$ ./cart.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^extras$ ./cart.php?gid=addons [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^renovar-dominio$ ./cart.php?gid=renewals [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^registrar-dominio$ ./cart.php?a=add&domain=register [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^pagamentos-multiplos$ ./clientarea.php?action=masspay&all=true [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^adicionar-credito$ ./clientarea.php?action=addfunds [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^cartao-credito$ ./clientarea.php?action=creditcard [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^base-de-conhecimento$ ./knowledgebase.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^downloads$ ./downloads.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^status-da-rede$ ./serverstatus.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^sub-contas$ ./clientarea.php?action=contacts [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^emails-enviados$ ./clientarea.php?action=emails [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^mudar-senha$ ./clientarea.php?action=changepw [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^afiliados$ ./affiliates.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^suporte$ ./submitticket.php?step=2&deptid=1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^transferencia-dominio$ ./cart.php?a=add&domain=transfer [L,NC]
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to change your urls on your views ? If it is a website, it is not something good to have multpile differents url for one page.

Comment: `.htaccess` can not _alter_ the HTML code that any file or script is outputting. You need to change the URLs in your HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have no uniform pattern for your mappings. You must have first one rule above all others to prevent endless redirect loops

```
# prevent endless loop    
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

and then add the reverse mappings one by one for simple URLs

```
RewriteRule ^clientarea.php$ central-cliente [R,L]
```

or with a condition, if you have a query string

```
RewriteRule ^clientarea.php?action=details$ meus-dados [R,L]
```

will *not* work, because `?action=details` is not part of the URL path. You must have a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) with `%{QUERY_STRING}` for this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=details
RewriteRule ^clientarea.php$  meus-dados? [R,L]
```

The question mark `?` at the end suppresses the query string in the substitution URL.

Maybe, you can use a [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) with [`txt`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#txt) at least for the simple one to one redirects and maintain the list of mappings in a simple text file. But this is not much different from having a long list of `RewriteRule`s in your .htaccess.

Comment: Great! My .htaccess is now like this: http://pastebin.com/w89wuhkH

Take into account this isn't root .htaccess, it's from /panel/ directory only. Those security codes at the bottom seems reliable?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user2056484 You have a typo in `RewriteBase /painel/` and please see updated answer regarding query strings.